# trigonometry simplifying with double angle

Tags: trigonometry

https://i.stack.imgur.com/nABRS.jpg

can someone tell me how am i supposed to find theta/alpha?
i’m literally on my 3rd hour trying to solve this. i just can’t seem to get theta/alpha.

i have attached the image above. i have tried many ways to simplify it, until the very final step in the picture i have attached. how am I suppose to continue to find the theta/alpha value?

edit: the answer for theta/alpha is actually 1/2. but how??? i’m losing my mind

Comment: In the second denominator, is that supposed to be $1-2$ in stead of $2-2$?

Comment: @B. Goddard, nope. the equation is fully correct up to that, as shown in the picture. i basically flip the both fractions over

Comment: Please type your question rather than posting an image since images cannot be searched.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: Such ugly drafts are not acceptable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using double angle formulae for sin and cos we get

$$\frac{\sin \theta}{\sin \alpha} = \frac{\cos \theta}{1+\cos \alpha}$$

which we re-arrange as

$$\frac{\sin \theta}{\cos \theta} = \frac{\sin \alpha}{1+\cos \alpha}.$$

By well-known identities this is

$$\tan \theta = \tan \alpha/2$$

So $\theta = \alpha/2 + k\pi.$